# Unable to get screen signal after purge FGLRX

Tags: ati

I thought that my ATI driver was not running well so I wanted to re-instal it completely. 
I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

and after a boot I wanted to intal the ATI driver BUT at the boot no more signal to my screen.

Since, every time **I turn on my PC it gets to purple screen and then screen shuts down !**

Note that:

- Even if the screen is off, PC seems to be running almost well: I m
  still able to use my network to access data shared with NFS.
- Using live USB I have no screen problem.
- I tried to plug my screen on an [alternative output](https://askubuntu.com/q/58267/32413) but it did not work.
- I tried *CTRL+ALT+F1* while being on purple screen but it does not do anything, screen shut down anyway.
- I m going to try [the *SHIFT* thing](https://askubuntu.com/q/38834/32413) and learn from [blackscreen wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen)...

Comment: FYI, you actually ended up uninstalling BOTH the AMD driver and the open source driver.

Comment: yes I though that my open source driver where still there.  I will remember it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears you left out a few commands;

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Your X server configuration likely lists no driver so it will not load properly. You may be able to recover by following the guide by effenburg on this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857059&highlight=effenberg%20ati)

Comment: yes I though that my open source driver was still there and I was on my way to run the install command just after reboot. But it appears that this was not a good idea, oups! Thank you for your link it helped me to solve the issue.